How to install packages with pip3 to correct interpreter?
I was using pip3 to install some packages in my Mac, and found out that there are two different version of python in my laptop. One is install with Homebrew, and another is the global interpreter. The python version install with Homebrew was python 3.11.8. However, the global python version in my Mac was 3.9.6. When typing which python3 in the terminal, I get /usr/bin/python3, and python3 --version gave Python 3.9.6. However, when typing which python3.11, I got /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.11, and python3.11 --version gave Python 3.11.8, which is the interpreter I would like to use.
Packages installed with pip3 are now installed under python 3.9.6. How can I set 3.11 as my default interpreter, so that the packages install with pip3 can be installed to the 3.11 interpreter?

Using a absolute path to interpreter will always use correct location when installing packages. Next, if you want to make sure that when you write "python" to shell prompt and it should default 3.11.8 thats in your homebrew/bin path - you need to make sure that /opt/homebrew/bin/  is first in the PATH environment variable.

Try this command:
python3.11 -m pip install ...

actually, I recommend using pyenv for dealing with python versions on mac.
